# How to fix audio clipping in Adobe Audition?

Tags: audio

I am editing audio from video that was captured from the sound board. The audio was recorded too loud since someone turned up the board and and the bass and vocals sound scratchy. I have brought the levels down a bit to normalize them but still have the scratchy sound with the vocals. Is there an effect in Adobe Audition to help this?

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Audition 3 there is Effects... Restoration... Clip Restoration (process).